# Changing Android Theme Attribute at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

I am developing an application where I have to change the attributes of the theme.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To set the theme dynamically at runtime, call setTheme() in your activity's onCreate() method, before calling setContentView(). To change the theme, you simply need to restart your activity.

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html) on how dynamically apply themes.

and [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) one too.

Comment: The question was on how to set a Theme Attribute, not a Theme.